# How to save Venn diagram as PNG in python venn

Tags: python, png, visualization, venn

https://github.com/LankyCyril/pyvenn/blob/master/pyvenn-demo.ipynb
in this library, I want to know How to save Venn diagram as PNG

I knew the way how to save Venn diagram as PNG in **matplotlib_venn**
But, I don't know that way in **Venn**
I want to save the venn diagram as PNG

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from venn import venn
%matplotlib inline

musicians = {
    "Members of The Beatles": {"Paul McCartney", "John Lennon", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"},
    "Guitarists": {"John Lennon", "George Harrison", "Jimi Hendrix", "Eric Clapton", "Carlos Santana"},
    "Played at Woodstock": {"Jimi Hendrix", "Carlos Santana", "Keith Moon"}
}
# Save the figure
venn(musicians).get_figure().savefig("output.png")
```

Comment: Thank you 
you are my angel !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!